# MVC 3 - Client validation of list

Tags: jquery, validation, list, asp.net-mvc-3

I've got the following **Model**

```
public class ProductLang
{
  public int productID { get; set; }

  public int langID { get; set; }

  [Required, StringLength(150)]
  public string name { get; set; }

  [AllowHtml]
  public string description { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
  return View(_db.Products.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id.Equals(id)).ProductLangs);
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductLang>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
  @Html.Hidden("id", Model.FirstOrDefault().productID)

  @foreach (var productLang in Model) {
    <div>
      @Html.Hidden("prodLang.Index", productLang.idLingua)
      @Html.Hidden("prodLang[" + productLang.langID + "].productID", productLang.productID)
      @Html.Hidden("prodLang[" + productLang.langID + "].langID", productLang.langID)

      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("prodLang" + productLang.langID + "__nome", "Name")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBox("prodLang[" + productLang.langID + "].name", productLang.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("prodLang[" + productLang.langID + "].name")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.Label("prodLang" + productLang.langID + "__description", "Description")
      </div>
      <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextArea("prodLang[" + productLang.langID + "].description", productLang.description)
      </div>
    </div>
  } 

  <input type="submit" value="EDIT" />
}
```

I've got others view and controller where jquery unobstrusive validation works, but not here.  I assume because I've got a List. 
In fact, if I made a view with only one object, works.

How can I bind jquery unobstrusive validation to a list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of writing those ugly `foreach` loops and trying to find suitable names for your inputs in your view you could consider using an editor template as it will make your view much more simpler:

```
@model IEnumerable<ProductLang>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @Html.Hidden("id", Model.FirstOrDefault().productID)
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="EDIT" />
}
```

and then inside the corresponding editor template (`~/Views/Home/EditorTemplates/ProductLang.cshtml`):

```
@model ProductLang
<div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.idLingua)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.productID)
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.langID)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.name, "Name")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.description, "Description")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.description)
    </div>
</div>
```

Now you will find out that everything auto-magically comes to its place: correct naming convention so that when you postback the default model binder will be able to reconstruct the view model, client and server side validation working, clean views, happy users :-)